# wait until page.click returns true

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm scraping a website [weather.com](https://www.weather.com), I want to click on an html element to fetch data and show it, then I scrape that data.

But it doesn't always work for me, most of the time the click doesn't happen and I get an error trying to scrape those elements

```
await page.waitFor('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)')
await page.click('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)')
```

What should I do to ensure that the click happens?

Comment: Can you give us more hint on your question, for example by providing more information such as what kind of package are you using? what kind of error you are encountering with.

Comment: @FelixFong i'm using puppeteer as mentioned in the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying you want the element to be visible with

`await page.waitFor('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)', { visible:true })`
(do you notice the `{visible:true}` option?)

because the element could be in the page but not clickable when `waitFor` finds it.

More details

- when you use `waitFor` with a selector you're using `waitForSelector` under the hood ([see the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args]))
- `waitForSelector` has a series of options ([see the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options]))
- one of the options is `visible`, the docs say

> wait for an element to be present in DOM and to be visible, i.e. to not have `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` CSS properties. Defaults to `false`.

Last but not least: @FeliFong asked you something more about your problem because you're not providing enough info about it. You could

- specify which is the page you're trying to fetch from (if it's publicly available)
- otherwise, you could make a GitHub repo, stripe out everything from your project leaving just the table you're speaking about and the Puppeteer script
- generally, when you're making a repo you find the issue yourself (it happened me lot and lot of times)
- if you don't solve the problem yourself making the repo... that's ok, we're here for that, but it's far and far easier to download a repo, launch it, fix the problem, make a pull request to you and then coming back here and giving you some explanations.
  It's useful for us but mostly for you because I tried to reply you... but I can't know if the solution I provided suite your needs... If I had the chance of checking it with a repo of your, I would have been sure I had solved the problem

[UPDATE]
I fixed the issue on the repository you provided me, accept my PR on GitHub.

What I've done: I made some tests and I don't know what the hell "blocks" (or, better, stops from waiting) Puppeteer in that site... but it doesn't matter, this is my code

```
let i = 0;
    let found = false;
    const maxRetries = 100;
    do {
        // waits for the element we need to click
        await page.waitForSelector('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)')
        // clicks it
        await page.click('#twc-scrollabe > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)')
        try {
            // waits for the content we need
            await page.waitForSelector('tr:nth-child(3) > td.sunrise > div > span:nth-child(2)', {timeout:1000});
            // if the content won't be showed the code doesn't go on and the next line won't be reached
            found = true;
        } catch(e) {}
    } while(!found || i > maxRetries) // the maxRetries variable is mere prudence
```

- waits for the element we need to click
- clicks it
- waits for the detailed content to be showed (with a timeout of 1000 ms)
- if it won't be showed simply retries (with a maximum of 100 times)
- then go ahead
  after the first click, your script go ahead at a fast pace

Comment: thank you for your kind reply
this is the page I'm trying to get data from https://weather.com/fr-DZ/temps/10jours/l/AGXX0383:1:AG , each row is clickable then it changes its class and shows more rows for details
I will create a repo for this problem in a moment, I will try to stripe out everything else because there is a lot of code
FYI, I tried running the script one last last time and it worked like a charm without changing anything, but I'm sure it won't work like this the next time

Comment: The untrustworthiness of the E2E scripts/tests is a classic, it gets some time and practice to understand why it happens and how to avoid that 

Comment: here is the repo https://github.com/imadyaici/weather_scraper
the commented code in scraper.js works fine because it doesn't have to click

Comment: I think you forgot the `i++`, didn't you?

Comment: well it doesn't totally work, when I added more locations the script stopped after 4-5 executions

Comment: Yes I forgot it! Where does it stop?

Comment: yes it does unfortunately, just uncomment more lines in locations.js and test

Comment: Please give me some more details... try

- placing `console.log` before any step of your script and check where it stops exactly

- try to understand if it's related to the nth running time or with the page you'are scraping

- remove parts of the script to understand both where it stops and if it's related with the order of the stuff

- debug it with `npx` if needed

In the end: give me a line of code that doesn't work and explain me the checks you've done your own because, otherwise, I can't help you.

Comment: Consider that even before my PR you didn't give me detailed info and when I opened your code... I completely deleted all the code contained into the `page.evaluate` call and it happened the same... so I could concentrate on a few lines of code instead of the whole script... this process is needed if you want to be helped 

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry if I couldn't be very specific in my problem. I used `console.log` inside the "click loop" and I saw that it doesn't go inside it sometimes and it was because this page looks like it never finishes loading, so i removed the `networkidle0` condition and it works after 3-4 clicks. I thought about this because when I try it manually I'm able to click on it even before the page finishes loading.

Comment: Yep in my PR I forgot to remove it because I tried all the available options (networkidle2, networkidle0 etc.) but no one worked so removing it is right. Does it always work now?

Comment: yes it works, it tries to click 6-7 times on that `tr` and then it succeeds, thank you